# Activity doesn't start after startActivity(intent)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, activity-lifecycle

I am working on the driver application of a cab/taxi booking system. Application has foreground service. Service starts to work with this code in MainActivity:

```
Intent myService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OnLineForegroundService.class);
startForegroundService(myService);
```

This service starts NewOrderActivity by trigger using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(OnLineForegroundService.this, NewOrderActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("newOrder", newOrder);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                      
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

After that in NewOrderActivity application starts TripActivity (by user tap):

```
//some finish service code
...

Intent intent = new Intent(NewOrderActivity.this, TripActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("order", newOrder);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

and the last step is the end of the trip:

```
//TripActivity

Intent i = new Intent(TripActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("showOnLineDialog", true);
startActivity(i);
finishAffinity();
```

[image]

These actions are performed cyclically. Sometimes (very rarely) NewOrderActivity doesn't start after `startActivity(intent)`. Even code in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` or `onResume()` in NewOrderActivity does not perform. Just nothing happens in the case when some activity is in the foreground. When the application is in the background (except foreground service) - application goes to the foreground and shows last opened activity but not NewOrderActivity.
What could be the problem? I suppose that problem may be in Activity lifecycle and flags (`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and  `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`) but not sure about it.

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".TaxiApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.NewOrderActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.TripActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <service android:name=".services.OnLineForegroundService" />
</application>
```

Comment: try `conext.startActivity(intent)`

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher What kind of context? `getApplicationContext()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think starting an activity from a service with the service's context is a good idea, try using application context. 
Change this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(OnLineForegroundService.this, NewOrderActivity.class);
```

to this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewOrderActivity.class);
```